# Counting the inequalities in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that are basically the same.

However in a particular column there are some rows where the values (floats) are different.

I would like to calculate the number of rows where the values are different.

This task seem pretty simple if not for the fact of the following two things

- They are floats so a normal equality sometimes gives different to two rows that are basically the same

And the most important thing

- The column has Nans . When I compare Nans they are deemed different. I don't want to count two rows with Nans as unequal but as equal. They should not be considered in the count

How can I compare a series of floats when there are Nans in it

Answer (score 2):

use `round` and `compare` from pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

d1 = {"col": [7.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, None, 1.9, 1.3]}
d2 = {"col": [7.1, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, None, 1.2, None]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

# to deal with the precision issue, say we want to round to 4 decimal place
df1["col"] = df1["col"].round(4)
df2["col"] = df2["col"].round(4)

# returns a dataframe with the differences
comparison = df1.compare(df2)

print(comparison)
print("different rows count:", len(comparison))
```

the output would be

```
   col      
  self other
1  2.0   2.5
5  1.9   1.2
6  1.3   NaN
different rows count: 3
```

Comment: Excellent, I will try that with my data. I suppose also that a bonus is that I can get the indexes of the differences as `comparison.index.to_list()`, right?

Comment: Oh, I found a tiny thing. Normally a df has other columns so the comparison might be `comparison = df1['col'].compare(df2['col'])` so that it takes into account only the column we are interested

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with `equal_nan=True` parameter, if necessary set precision by `rtol` parameter, last for count `True`s use `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan, 10.12],
                   'b':[np.nan, 10.121231]})

out = np.isclose(df.a, df.b, equal_nan=True, rtol = 0.003)
print (out)
[ True  True]

print (out.sum())
2

different = len(out) - out.sum()
0
```

Comment: ok but I have to find the number of different rows, not equal.

Comment: @KansaiRobot - Use `different = len(out) - out.sum()`